# Dynamic Form Creation and submission in OOP

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop

I'm trying to create a class to dynamically create a form and then submit the form. it's a simple class but now I have lost my way.

```
       var creathtml=function(){

       this.createform=function(o,title){

        var openingtag="<form action='#' class='form-horizontal well' onSubmit='this.submitform'><fieldset><legend>"+title+"</legend>";
        var fields="";

        for (var i=0; i<o.length; i++)
        {

            if(o[i].type=='input')
            {

            fields+="<div class='control-group'><label class='control-label' for='"+o[i].id+"'>"+o[i].label+"</label><div class='controls'><input type='"+o[i].subtype+"'  id='"+o[i].id+"' class='"+o[i].class+"'></div></div>";
            }

            if(o[i].type=='button')
            {

            fields+="<div class='control-group'><div class='controls'><button type='"+o[i].subtype+"'  id='"+o[i].id+"' class='"+o[i].class+"'>"+title+"</button></div></div>";
            }



        }

        var closingtag="</fieldset></form>";
            $(body).html (openingtag+fields+closingtag;

        };

    this.submitform=function()

        {

         console.log('mnmnmnmn');

                     return false;          
        }   

    }
```

**Usage**

```
            var obj= new creathtml;

                var  h=obj.createform([
             {'type':'input','subtype':'input','name':'Wow','label':'Item Name','id':'itmname','class':''},

             {'type':'input','subtype':'input','name':'hello','label':'Item Code','id':'hello','class':''},

             {'type':'input','subtype':'input','name':'hello','label':'Item Code','id':'hello2','class':''}, 
         {'type':'button','subtype':'submit','name':'submit','label':'Null','id':'submit','class':'btn btn-primary'}

             ],'Create New Items');
```

i have successfully created the HTML and populated on DOM. but don't know how to detect the form submission or create the submit method for this particular class?

this is my first time trying in javascript OOP , so if doing wrong please suggest the right way if possible

Answer (score 0):

You're already detecting a form submission with `onSubmit='this.submitform'`. Also, you might want to use a templating engine if possible.

Since you're already using jQuery though, adding a listener for the form submit would be ideal:

```
this.createform = function(o,title) {
    ...
    for (var i=0; i<o.length; i++)
    {
        ...
        $('.' + o[i].formClass).on('submit', function() {
            console.log('handle form submit here');
        });
    }
...
};
```

Comment: `this.submitform` is not working as expected. Secondly i want to use form listener in the class not out of the class. how i can do it.

Comment: `$('.form-horizontal')` ?

Comment: it is not obvious that same class would be used. it may be different for each form template.

Comment: `$('.' + formClassName)`

Comment: OK how i can use in oop style?

Comment: declare the listener inside `createform`

Comment: i tried but not working. could you please edit your answer with your solution

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35154/discussion-between-sushain97-and-muhammad-haseeb-khan)